# In a way vs in a state

Tags: phrase-usage

When he came to home  he was wet up to knees . While describing this situation which phrase below would be better.

> He came to home in a way that is wet up to knees
>
> He came to home in a state that is wet up to knees

Comment: Would you describe with other words what did you try to say with your sentences?

Answer (score 3):

*In a way* describes the manner in which someone did something.

"I styled my hair in a way that made it look thicker."

*In a state* describes the condition someone or something was in.

"The room was in a state of confusion."

*Wet up to the knees* clearly describes someone's state, so it's unnecessary to include the words *in a state.*

Comment: Would it be grammatically correct if I use in a state in this sentence?

Comment: In which sentence?

Comment: He came to home in a state that is wet up to knees

Comment: That is a more succinct answer.

Comment: As Jan's answer says, both _to_ and _in a state that is_ are redundant - and we would say 'wet up to _the_ knees'.

Comment: I know redundant but I just want to learn if use of in a state in this way is correct or not .

Comment: @Foreignstudent, in this sentence: "He came to home in a state that is wet up to knees," "in a state" is not only redundant but also used in a wrong way. The correct way might be: "He came home in a state of being wet up to knees," but then again, this is completely redundant. You use "in a way" to describe a method or a manner by which someone did something, so this doesn't make sense in your sentence, so it's not right, also.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to say this:

> He came home wet up to the knees.

Note, that you say "home" not "to home."

"In a way" means "how" (which shortly describes a process of making something), but it makes no sense to use it your sentence. An example of another sentence in which you can use "in the way:"

> He came home in a way that didn't wake anyone.

"In a state" simply means in which state something is. Being wet up to the knees is already a state, so you don't add "in a state." Another example in which you can use "in a state:"

> This country is in a state of well being.

Comment: But both are grammatically correct right?

Comment: No, I don't think that any of those 2 examples are right and there are several mistakes in them. Do you have any reason to write them a such? Is my example not good enough? Do you think you must say "in a way" for grammar reasons or to emphasize it?

Comment: I just want to learn difference between two phrase as far as I search both are correct but as you say those are redudant.I agree with you your sentence much better than mine.

Comment: @Foreignstudent, "in a way" and "in a state" are redundant in the examples you made, but can be used in other examples as I added them in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

*In a way* is used frequently to say that something approximately meets the a requirement or criteria:

*"Did you finish the task?" He asked.*

*"In a way." She replied*
*"What do you mean?" He asked.*

*"I finished most of it..." She said.*

I think that, I can't get past what I see as idioms.
Both *in a way* and *in a state*  can be used to communicate that someone is overcome by emotions to the degree that is is evident by interacting with them. In the following, I have heard people use *in a way* in place of *in a state*, though it seems to be less natural to a US California English speaker.

*He came home in a state, and began to drink.*

However to use the non-idiomatic meaning of *in a state* requires more after it.

*San Francisco has declared a state of emergency*

The above is very official sounding, you would hear it in the news.

*The office was in a state of chaos.*

Both seem like they should not be put in to the middle of a sentence.
And let's look at *up to knees*. I have a feeling you were looking for *up to his knees* which means overwhelmed or encumbered, you could say:

*He is up to his knees in debt.*

There is a misplaced *to*, *to* should follow *home*.

Overall I think there is missing context, no object. The best I can do  with that sentence is this:

*He came home in a state; he was up to his knees in debt.*

I had to make up an object for this, but replace *debt* with whatever fits here.